# Are the alert and confirm functions built into JavaScript, or are they part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript

Are the `alert` and `confirm` functions built in to JavaScript, or are they part of the DOM?

Bonus points if you can refer me to a reference that will allow me to easily tell what functions are directly built in to JavaScript.

Comment: All DOM level 0: https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Tags?tag=DOM_0

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf contains everything about JavaScript itself that is standardized. Enjoy reading it (not ironic, it is actually interesting)

Comment: What exactly do you need? Dialog functions are senseless in environments like `nodejs`. But they are present in e.g. Adobe's scripting.

Comment: Actually, I'm authoring a paper meant to introduce other developers to the JavaScript language.  I understand that some functions, such as `string.join`, are part of the language.  Some other functions, such as `document.getElementById`, are part of the DOM.  I want to know where `alert` and `confirm` fit into the picture.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: I don't know why, but when I click on any link on that page, it takes me to the Japanese translation. :|

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies The DOM is only a part of the browser object model. In short, you have the JavaScript language on one side, and the browser object model on the other side, which includes the DOM and dozens of other technologies (like Ajax, for instance).

Comment: @ajax81, well I can't explain the Japanese, but I get the French. Weird.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Actually, it looks like the page just isn't organized well.  The same material is linked in three different places, each to a separate language.  There doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason to the layout/order of the page, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are part of what is commonly referred to as [DOM level 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Legacy_DOM) which isn't part of any standard.

MDN has a [good JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript). It doesn't include objects that aren't part of core JS (although other sections on the site do cover DOM and other APIs).

Comment: [What do you mean not part of any standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-alert)

Answer (score 7):

These functions are usually only available in a browser environment, but they are not part of any standard , this is referred to as DOM level 0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

To get a better idea of what the difference is between javascript and the DOM, read this article
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview

Comment: They are specified in the HTML standard: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#user-prompts

Answer (score 1):

[alert](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-alert) is one of the user prompts defined in the WHATWG HTML specification